# Export GT table with Officer

Tags: r, r-markdown, officer, gt

I am trying to export a gt table using the package officer but I get this error message.

> Error in UseMethod("ph_with", value) :
> no applicable method for 'ph_with' applied to an object of class "c('gt_tbl', 'list')"

I already updated officer and all the packages I have installed. I also installed the github version.  Do you have any idea how to export it?

Thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately as of the moment `gt` only supports HTML output. See https://gt.rstudio.com/